# How to save and close a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question have many answers out there but none of those answers solved my problem.  I have a modal with some `<select>` tags.  I am trying to save the values from the `select options`.  after they click `Save` the modal should close but not `submit` the result yet because the user still need to review stuff after they click `save` on the modal.

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div id="1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;       </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    //select tags go here
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="save" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan save-details" type="button" name="save-details">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#save').click(function() {
$('#1').modal('hide');
 });
```

Since my code is really long, I just copied a modal from google but I added my `Save` button, so this is the real `Save` button that my modal is using.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I changed the id number to letters so now the code doesn't include any id starting with number, thanks.

PS still need help =/

**EDIT**

I also tried this one and it did not work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#save').click(function(){
$('#modal_1').modal('hide');//modal_1 is the id 1
 }); 

});
```

Comment: As mentionned by Eshwaren and I, `id=1` is not valid. identifier must start by an alphabetical char (call it `m1` or `d1`) . This has to be replaced in both html and js part (Edit your question to be sure it's ok :) ). 
As You only gave a part of your code, it may have some other error, but I just have to point the `onclick="save()"` may do thing unpredictable as we have not it's code (and it's probably may interfer with the `$("#save").click()` event.

Comment: Perhaps a https://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure the `id=1` is fine, but you can use this code to simulate a click on the close button (or you can add an id or a class to it).

You may have to remove the `onclick="save()"`

```
data = {};
$("#save").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent de default action, which is to submit
  // save your value where you want
  data.select = $("#exampleSelect").value();
  // or call the save function here
  // save();
  $(this).prev().click();

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check my answer, I corrected the last line : `$(this).prev().click()`

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

**HTML**

```
<div id="someModalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;       </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <select id="exampleSelect">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="save" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan save-details" type="button" name="save-details">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  $select_value = $("#exampleSelect").value();
  $('#someModalId').modal('hide');
});
```

1. Give your select a name or id
2. Set the value of select to a global variable. Make sure to declare the variable at the top if you are getting an error.

Comment: The issue is that even when I click `save` the modal doesnt hide

Comment: You cannot use numbers in the beginning of an ID. I didn't notice this just now. Sorry.

Comment: Edited the answer. Removed numbered ID.

Answer (score 4):

```
<button id="save" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan save-details" type="button" name="save-details" onclick="save()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalList" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

this worked very well for me, and its a simple way to do it. after the onclick I used the data-toggle, data-target and data-dismiss

in the js function save() I didn't need to code anything but to save data into to my database

```
// Insere notas na base de dados
function save() {
  console.log("func guardar");
  if ($("#message-text").val() == "") {
    alert("Texto vazio");
  } else {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../portal/portalphp/notas.php",
        data: {
          num: num,
          text: $("#message-text").val()
        }
      }).done(function (msg) {
        if (msg == 1) {
          //alert("Nota guardada com sucesso");
          readyNotas(num);
          console.log("func guardar done == 1");
        } else {
          alert("Erro: não foi possivel guardar");
        }
      });
      texto.value = "";
    });
    console.log("func guardar ready");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the js function save()?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove `onclick="save()"` from your button.  You don't need that when you are using the on click function directly `$('#save').click(function()...`

As was pointed out in the comments by @Eshwaren, you can't use a number to start an `id`, so you need fix that as well.

To get the value from a select, you have to be able to identify it.  A simple solution would be to give your select element an `ID`.

For example:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <select id="data_1">
    </select>
</div>
```

In your code, you can then assign the value of the select element to a variable.

For example:

```
var data_1;
$('#save').click(function() {
  data_1  = $("#data_1").value();
  $('#modalid').modal('hide');
});
```

You can then use that variable elsewhere in your code.

There are many more possibilities for solving this, but the root of the issue is being able to identify the select elements in code and recording their respective values.

Comment: Not sure why, but for some reason I can't hide my modal

Answer (score 2):

thats my modal window

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Column Preferences",
        button: "save",
        width: 750,
        height: 620
});
```

try this to close or hide the window

```
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working with a hint from Ricardo Almeida:

```
<%=form_with id: :friend_email_form, url: friend_emails_create_path do |f|%>

                      # form fields entered here

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send Email", class: 'btn btn-primary', "onclick":"submit_form();", "data-dismiss":"modal"%>
</div>

 <script>
    function submit_form() {
      document.getElementById('friend_email_form').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add 'data-dismiss="modal"' when click save

example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button"  id="test2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="test" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputState">State</label>
                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      <option>...</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                      Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button"  id="test2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">
    +Add New
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="test" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputCity">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputState">State</label>
                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      <option>...</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                      Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).